# numpy: replicating each 1-d array element n times

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list/array of elements, such as `[0, 1, 2]`, what is the most ***numpy**thonic* way to replicate each element **n** times and store the result in a 1-d array, such as (for n=3) `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.repeat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
In [86]: np.repeat([0, 1, 2], 3)
Out[86]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: I knew I missed the obvious solution. Thanks!